# Is it possible to add a transition effect when changing my theme stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I need to know how I can add a transition effect when my theme stylesheet changes when clicking on the button. The following is my code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const themeStylesheet = document.getElementById('theme');

  const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  if (storedTheme) {
    themeStylesheet.href = storedTheme;
  }
  const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme-toggley');
  themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // if it's light -> go dark
    if (themeStylesheet.href.includes('light')) {
      themeStylesheet.href = 'css/dark-theme.css';




    } else {
      // if it's dark -> go light
      themeStylesheet.href = 'css/light-theme.css';




    }
    // save the preference to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeStylesheet.href)

  })
})
```

```html
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/light-theme.css" />
<button id="theme-toggley">Light</button>
```

Comment: We cannot have a transition effect on changing the style sheets, instead, you can change the class name of root element, and can change the theme based on that, in that scenario, you can do that

Comment: You might want to use `preferrs-color-scheme` to use the user's default setting.

Answer (score 2):

just adding a

```css
*{
 transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

will work

eg:-

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

var lightTheme = document.getElementById('light-theme'),
darkTheme = document.getElementById("dark-theme");
var currentTheme;
function setTheme (themeId){
    currentTheme = themeId;
    document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet].theme").forEach(link=>{
        link.removeAttribute("rel");
    })
    document.querySelector(`#${themeId}`).setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
}

const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
if(storedTheme){
    if(storedTheme == "light-theme"){
        setTheme("dark-theme")
    }else{
        setTheme("light-theme")
    }
}else{
    setTheme("light-theme")
}
const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme-toggley');
themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // if it's light -> go dark
    if(currentTheme == "light-theme"){
        setTheme("dark-theme")
    } else {
        // if it's dark -> go light
        setTheme("light-theme")
    }
    // save the preference to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('theme',currentTheme)
     
})
})
```

```css
*{
/*main*/
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
button{
    padding:10px ;border-radius:15px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link id="light-theme" type="text/css" class="theme" href="data:text/css;utf8,button{ color : black; background-color: white ;}" />
<link id="dark-theme"  type="text/css" class="theme" href="data:text/css;utf8,button{ color : white; background-color: black ;}" />
<button id="theme-toggley">Light</button>
```